# Disable "share a link" popup?

Tags: discussion, user-interface

Is there some way of disabling that annoying "share a link to this hot question to earn the publicist badge" message that keeps popping up all the time?!?
(I don't use Facebook or Twitter, and I'm not the least interested in earning the publicist badge.)

Comment: +1. The site is slowly becoming a mess of things that popup at you... I have still to find use of *any* of those things!

Comment: +1, I never knew what this popup could be good for. If I want to link to a question, then I know what I have to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got tired of seeing this pop-up, so I killed it.

Edit the user stylesheet for your browser (for me it was userContent.css); there are tons of tutorials online for where to find this for your OS/browser.

Add a line:

.share-tip {display:none!important;}

Restart your browser and you shouldn't see the pop-up any more.

**Note:** Jeff Atwood has said it's fine for me to post these instructions.  Some people have been surprised that I even bothered to ask, but I have been banned for similar things at other sites.

Answer (score 5):

A data point: as of right now, it seems that *no one* has been awarded the coveted publicist badge...

Comment: Over at [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/badges) it has been awarded 4 times, but this is also the _only_ badge awarded 10 times or less.

Comment: right, it is also one of the newest badges

Comment: Can you estimate how many times the popup has been shown? It'd be interesting to know the conversión rate

Answer (score -4):

This `<div>` only appears on "hot" questions

- on page load, while they are hot
- after upvoting a hot question

In both cases, there is only about a 20% chance of the event happening.

Comment: I understand that, but I would still like the chance to be 0%. An active user of the site is much more likely to look at "hot" questions than cold ones, and then this popup appears *way* more often than what is tolerable (IMHO).