# Are we "allowed" to disable the "share a link to this question" pop-up? And tell others how?

Tags: discussion

I found the "share a link" pop-up to be annoying ([as have others](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1531/disable-share-a-link-popup), apparently) and there doesn't seem to be a way to disable it on this site. So I figured out a way to disable it using a user stylesheet mod.  This mod, of course, disables it for my browser only and doesn't affect anyone else's experience nor is the site even able to tell I'm blocking it.

But my question is this: can I post my mod here or would be such a post be seen as "teaching people how to hack the site?"

Comment: how in the world could modifying the site in your browser to your needs be considered "hacking"?

Comment: @Jeff: Remember the controversy around adblocker-plus?  Folks were just blocking ads in their browser but sites were upset about it.  I view the "share a link" pop-up to be similar to advertising, so I thought using YOUR site to advocate something you might view as counter to your goals as somewhere between impolite and cause for censure.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Of course it's not "hacking", any more than changing your browser's display settings or using an unusual browser is hacking. (Except in the original, positive sense of the word.)

If it makes you feel any better, [Jeff Atwood himself has pointed to user scripts that change the behaviour of the site](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1309/allow-newline-in-comments/1313#1313).

Comment: Thanks.  I have been banned from other sites for giving instructions on how to block ads or other "features" of the sites when the provider does not want users avoiding pop-ups which (though annoying) support their revenue/traffic/social-media goals.

Comment: @Fixee: I suppose you're right, it's a greyer area than I thought.

Comment: @Fixee It is completely their fault and not yours since it is your action(accessing the website etc.) which makes them earn money, go up in the rankings etc. but as you say it is a long story to discuss here.